# Does adding more covariates always increase the condition number of the Hessian, and can you have a high-condition number but higher log-likelihood?

Tags: likelihood, condition-number

Does adding more covariates always increase the condition number of the Hessian, and can you have a high-condition number but higher log-likelihood/more optimal model?

Should we ever not use the model with a higher log-likelihood if the condition number on it is more than $10^{15},10^{16}$ or does the better model always have a lower condition number?

Should we rank models by whether its condition number is high?

Is there a condition-number versus log-likelihood trade-off?

Comment: if you have collinearity then you would probably use ridge regression, so the condition number would be lower, but that is not a likelihood...

Comment: A) yes adding more variables can only worsen the condition number (in "linear-type" problems). B) Condition number and log-likelihood are uncoupled ideas; there's no general relationship between them. C) If you're worried about condition number, why not do something like 1) variable selection 2) regularization .

Comment: One way to obtain intuitive and correct answers to all these questions is to contemplate adjoining a new explanatory variable that is a specified linear combination of some of the existing explanatory variables, thereby making the condition number infinite.  That won't change the likelihood at all, nor will it change any of the fitted values of the model.